# Rails, Heroku: Missing template application/not_found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

It appears that my Rails 5 app (only in production - on Heroku) causes these missing template errors for `application/not_found`. This error does not cause the app to crash though.

```
#<ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template application/not_found with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[nil], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: 
   * "/app/app/views" 
   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-authy-1.8.1/app/views" 
   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise_invitable-1.7.2/app/views" 
   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/devise-71fc5b351a8e/app/views" 
   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/kaminari-core-1.0.1/app/views" 
 >
```

---

I routed `*path` to `application#not_found` to catch misspelled requests.

In `ApplicationController`:

```
rescue_from (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) { |exception| handle_exception(exception, 404) }
rescue_from (AbstractController::ActionNotFound) { |exception| handle_exception(exception, 404) }
rescue_from (ActionController::RoutingError) { |exception| handle_exception(exception, 404) }


def not_found
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(params[:path] || 'Not Found')
end

protected

def handle_exception ex, status
    render_error ex, status
    logger.error ex
end

def render_error ex, status
    @status_code = status
    respond_to do |format|
        if status == 404
            format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found', status: status }
        end
        format.all { render nothing: true, status: status }
    end
end
```

I thought that by specifying `render template: 'errors/not_found'` Rails 'd know that a template got rendered.

Comment: Where is the `errors/not_found.html.erb` in your application located?

Comment: @spickermann `app/views/errors/not_found.html.haml`

Comment: @spickermann I mean it gets rendered, that's the thing. The error occurs simultaneously.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Because newer versions of Rails do not support the `:template` option anymore.

Comment: @spickermann `5.1.0.rc2`